# Mongodb returns empty array with query builder

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-builder, mongodb-java

I have the following documents in collection

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53202b3644aec3ce32afc40b"),
    "_class" : "com.brand.domain.House",
    "bedrooms" : 2,
    "uid" : "URErlrjldVhW",
    "price" : NumberLong(200),
    "type" : "RENT",
    "address" : " test",
    "details" : " test",
    "rentType" : "perMonth"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53202b4444aec3ce32afc40c"),
    "_class" : "com.brand.domain.House",
    "bedrooms" : 2,
    "uid" : "SHvPruOJuivg",
    "price" : NumberLong(300),
    "type" : "RENT",
    "address" : " ",
    "details" : " ",
    "rentType" : "perMonth"
}
```

And with the following query using query builder, it returns empty array

My input values are

```java
type : RENT
maxPrice : 5000
minPrice : 100
bedRooms : 2
```

And the query

```java
Query query = new Query(
    where("type")
    .is(form.getType())
    .and("price")
    .lte(form.getMaxPrice())
    /*.gte(form.getMinPrice())*/
    .and("bedRooms")
    .is(form.getMinBedRooms()));
```

And following are form fields

```java
private String type;
private long minPrice;
private long maxPrice;
private int minBedRooms;
```

Can any one kindly help me what is wrong with my query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't "Query" a sping data class? So then:

```java
    Query searchQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("type")
            .is("RENT")
            .and("price")
            .lte(5000)
            .and("bedrooms")
            .is(2));

    System.out.println( searchQuery );
```

Printing or logging the object usually help me see it is doing what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake.

Change **berdRooms** to **bedrooms**

According to JSON-RPC spec:

6.5. Case-Sensitivity of Procedure and Parameter Names

Conforming implementations MUST treat procedure and parameter names as being case-sensitive such the names bar and BAR would be seen as two distinct entities.